# How to add my own TIF file to Mapbox GL JS maps in my code?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to add a TIF file to my Mapbox GL JS code which is in html. I haven't found any relevant solution as to how I can add the file to my html code. Can anyone please tell me how to solve this? I need to upload the Georeferenced TIF file to my map in Mapbox GL JS.

Should I convert the TIF file to some other format? It will be better for me if I can upload the whole TIF file to Mapbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Change a map's style</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.2.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.2.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<style type='text/css'>
    #info {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 30%;
        padding: 8px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #222;
        background: #fff;
    }
</style>



<style>
    #menu {
        position: absolute;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
</style>

<div id='map'></div>
<div id='menu'>
    <input id='streets-v11' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='streets' checked='checked'>
    <label for='streets'>streets</label>
    <input id='light-v10' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='light'>
    <label for='light'>light</label>
    <input id='dark-v10' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='dark'>
    <label for='dark'>dark</label>
    <input id='outdoors-v11' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='outdoors'>
    <label for='outdoors'>outdoors</label>
    <input id='satellite-v9' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='satellite'>
    <label for='satellite'>satellite</label>
</div>
<pre id='info'></pre>
<script>



mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2lmYXQ1NzciLCJhIjoiY2p6dXNvN3ZnMGVqZTNjcDRrNWNqcTE5byJ9.Bg8-lwZjjNoswew2k1w2RA';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',


    zoom: 13,
    center: [90.3897, 23.7270]
});


// Add zoom and rotation controls to the map.
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
//for displaying the latlon of mouse curson in map
map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
        // e.point is the x, y coordinates of the mousemove event relative
        // to the top-left corner of the map
        JSON.stringify(e.point) + '<br />' +
        // e.lngLat is the longitude, latitude geographical position of the event
        JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.wrap());
});


var layerList = document.getElementById('menu');
var inputs = layerList.getElementsByTagName('input');

function switchLayer(layer) {
    var layerId = layer.target.id;
    map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/' + layerId);
}

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onclick = switchLayer;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am currently looking into a similar issue and may end up trying to overlay the raster geotiff on top of the map..

Comment: No, I couldn't add TIF file to Mapbox. I switched to Cesium.js globe and was able to add my TIF file there. You can also add them to google earth by uploading them.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update! I'll probably keep on trying with mapbox, since I don't have any other mapping options at the moment

Comment: Actually, Cesium can't do it even...

Comment: I actually could add TIF file in Cesium.js

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this (as you spoke about) is to convert the georeferenced image to another format. Here is an example of how to add a georeferenced image, as long as you know the geographic bounds :

```
            map.addSource("myImageSource", {
                "type": "image",
                "url": "test.gif",
                "coordinates": [
                    [-80.425, 46.437],
                    [-71.516, 46.437],
                    [-71.516, 37.936],
                    [-80.425, 37.936]
                ]
            });

        map.addLayer({
            "id": "overlay",
            "source": "myImageSource",
            "type": "raster",
            "paint": {
            "raster-opacity": 0.85
            }
        });
```

You can also see https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/ for more reference material.